# How to use bundle with local gems during Mina deployment of Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, mina

I'm deploying a Rails app with Mina `mina:deploy` which clones from a git repo and Bundler installs the gems.

```
# /config/deploy.rb
# ...
task :deploy => :environment do
  deploy do
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    # ...
  end
end
```

However, unlike when I `bundle install` manually, mina is installing each gem anew. With a healthy number of gems, this takes roughly 10 minutes to complete. How can I deploy while pointing bundler to use any locally available (already installed) gems where possible?

I've also tried replacing `invoke :'bundle:install'` with `queue! "bundle install --local"` with no change in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use a local copy of the gems that you have without checking `rubygems` so after installing gems you run `bundle package` to create a cache of the gems used and instead of running `bundle install` you should run `bundle install --local` to use only the cached copy of gems without checking the `rubygems.com` .

Comment: Cheers for this. Have you had success specifically with Mina? If so, can you post how you incorporate this into your deployment?